# Prove that $f$ is constant, when $ \operatorname{Re}(f)^m = \operatorname{Im}(f)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Take $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic function in $U$ and $U$ connected open subset. If exist $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ [
 \operatorname{Re}(f(z))]^m = [ \operatorname{Im}(f(z))]^n ,$$ $f$ is constant in $U$.

Note: The exercise requires using the theorem and equations of Cauchy-Riemann.

*NB:* An attempt is in the comments.

**Question**: In my first attemp, I want to see that is not possible that $det(A_{(x,y)})=0 \ \ \forall (x,y) \in U$

One possibilities is $v^{2n-2} (x,y) =0$. This implies that $f(x,y)=0$. But, is in this point. And others? $f=0$ ever?

Comment: Use the open mapping theorem.

Comment: My first attemp. I denote $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Using Cauhy-Riemann theorem, I know that $f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x.y)$ and $f$ satisfy Cauhy-Riemann equations. Deriving $u^m(x,y) - v^n(x,y)=0$, I have $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} mu^{m-1}(x,y)u_x(x,y) - nv^{n-1}(x,y)v_x(x,y) = 0\\  mu^{m-1}(x,y)u_y(x,y) - nv^{n-1}(x,y)v_y(x,y) = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Using the Cauchy-Riemman equations, I have $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} mu^{m-1}(x,y)u_x(x,y) + nv^{n-1}(x,y)u_y(x,y) = 0\\  mu^{m-1}(x,y)u_y(x,y) - nv^{n-1}(x,y)u_x(x,y) = 0 \end{array} \right.$$

Matrix, $$\underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}
mu^{m-1} & nv^{n-1} \\ 
-nv^{n-1} & mu^{m-1}
\end{matrix}\right)_{(x,y)}}_{A} \cdot \left(\begin{matrix} u_x \\
u_y \end{matrix}\right)_{(x,y)} = \underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\
0 \end{matrix}\right)}_{b}$$

Comment: I think for these sorts of things, the open mapping theorem is your friend, partly because it carries much intuition. The idea gets lost in the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: I wanna prove that $det(A) \not= 0$. Then, the matrix system has the trivial solution. And, using Cauchy-Riemann equations, I have that $f'=0$. Then $f$ is constant. 

But, how I prove that $det(A) \not= 0$?

Comment: By computation, the $\det$ is non zero for $(u,v) \neq 0$.

Comment: I calculate, $$det(A) = m^2u^{2m-2}(x,y) + n^2 v^{2m-2}.$$ 
Multiplying by $u^2(x,y)$, I have
$$det(A)=0 \leftrightarrow m^2u^{2m}(x,y) + n^2u^2(x,y) v^{2n-2}(x,y) = 0$$

Using the hypothesis, $u^{2m}(x,y) = v^{2n}(x,y)$, then $$det(A)=0 \leftrightarrow v^{2n-2}(x,y) \Big[m^2v^{2}(x,y) + n^2u^2(x,y) \Big] = 0$$

But, the condition depend of the point $(x,y)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $C=\{ z | (\operatorname{re} z)^m = (\operatorname{im} z)^n \}$ contains no open sets.

The open mapping theorem shows that a non constant $f$ maps open sets into open sets.

**Alternative**:

Note that it is sufficient to show that if $f(z) \neq 0$, then $f'(z) = 0$.
In particular, this implies that $f'(z) = 0$ everywhere in $U$.

To see this, suppose $f'(z) \ne 0$, then we must have $f(z) = 0$, but since
$f'(z) \neq 0$, we have $f(w) \neq 0$ for all $w$ in some neighbourhood of $z$ and hence $f'(w) = 0$ for all $w$ in some neighbourhood of $z$.
Continuity then shows that $f'(z) = 0$, a contradiction.

So, we can suppose that $f(z) \neq 0$. The rest of the argument follows
the OPs comments above.

In particular, we consider $f$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, $(x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y), v(x,y))$, that satisfies
The Cauchy Riemann equations.

Define $\phi(a,b) = a^m-b^n$, then since $\phi(u(x,y),v(x,y)) = 0$, we
have, suppressing the parameters for brevity, ${\partial \phi \over \partial a} {\partial u \over \partial x} +
{\partial \phi \over \partial b} {\partial v \over \partial x} = 0$
and 
${\partial \phi \over \partial a} {\partial u \over \partial y} +
{\partial \phi \over \partial b} {\partial v \over \partial y} = 0$.
Substituting the Cauchy Riemann equalities into the second equation
gives
$-{\partial \phi \over \partial a} {\partial v \over \partial x} +
{\partial \phi \over \partial b} {\partial u \over \partial x} = 0$.

Writing as a matrix gives
$\begin{bmatrix} {\partial \phi \over \partial a} & {\partial \phi \over \partial b}\\
{\partial \phi \over \partial b} & -{\partial \phi \over \partial a}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} {\partial u \over \partial x} \\ {\partial y \over \partial x}
\end{bmatrix} = 0$ and we see that the left hand side is invertible
**iff** $({\partial \phi \over \partial a},{\partial \phi \over \partial a}) \neq 0$.

Since we have presumed $f(z) \neq 0$, it is straightforward to check
that $({\partial \phi \over \partial a},{\partial \phi \over \partial a}) \neq 0$ and hence $f'(z) = 0$.

Comment: The problem is that the exercise requires using the theorem and equations of Cauchy-Riemman.

Comment: You might want to add that constraint to the question.

Comment: I am thinking on your reasoning. What happens if C does not contain open sets?  What is the contradiction with open mapping theorem ?

Comment: If $f$ is non constant and analytic then $f(B(z_0,r))$ is open and cannot be contained in $C$.

Comment: Ok. And how to prove that $C$ contains no open sets?

Comment: Show that the set $K=\{ (x,y) | x^m = y^n \}$ contains no open sets. For example, if $(x,y) \in K$ then $(x+h,y) \notin K$ for small $h \neq 0$. In fact, there are only finitely many $h$ such that $(x+h,y) \in C$.

Comment: I added an alternative answer along the lines of the one you had in the comments. You were almost there.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your reasoning. 

Your first step was prove this: "For each $z \in U$, if $f(z) \not= 0$, then $f'(z)=0$". Or equivalently, "For each $z \in U$, if $f'(z) \not= 0$, then $f(z)=0$". Your prove is based on reduction to absurdity.

So, you take $z \in U : f'(z)\not = 0$ and $f(z)\not=0$. Since $f'(z)\not=0$, exists $\delta>0 \ : \ B(z,\delta)\subset U$ and $$f(w)\not=0 \ \forall w\in B(z,\delta).$$

Why $f'(w)= 0 \ \forall w\in B(z,\delta)$?

Comment: Here is the reasoning: First I show that if it is true that whenever $f(z) \neq 0$ we have $f'(z) = 0$ then, in fact, we have $f'(z) = 0$ everywhere (which is what we want to show). That means we need only show $f'(z) = 0$ when $f(z) \neq 0$.

Comment: If $f'(z) \neq 0$, then the definition of $f'$ shows that in a small neighbourhood of $z$ we must have $f(w) \neq 0$ (since $f(w) \approx f(z) + f'(z) (w-z) =  f'(z) (w-z)$).

Comment: Why if $f(z)\not=0$ we have $f'(z)=0$ everywhere? I don't understand how $f'$  is always zero suposing that exists a point on $f$ isn't zero.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed here. Let Condition 'Z' be true **iff** whenever $f(z) \neq 0$ we have $f'(z) = 0$. Then, it is a lemma that if 'Z'' is true, then we have $f'(z) = 0$ everywhere. That is all that says.

Comment: In your comments to your question, you have proved that if $f(z) \neq 0$, then $f'(z) = 0$. So, you have proved that Condition 'Z' holds. It follows from the lemma that $f'(z) = 0$ and connectedness does the rest.